# Add CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an external css sheet and I use this JS code:

```
  var link = document.URL;  


  if (link.indexOf('http://194.71.107.82/') != -1) 
  {

  document.write("<style>body { background-color:#000 }</style>");


  }
  else
  {
  window.location.replace('http://194.71.107.82/')
  }
```

But there's a problem:
When he rewrites the code with document.write it starts reloading, so the script starts again and writes again, so it starts navigating again... It got in a loop...

So what can I do to don't get it in a loop?

**EDIT** so... Now I used

```
document.getElementById("fp").style.display = "none";
```

But nothing happened? The Div stayed visible?

Comment: Use Yepnope.JS http://yepnopejs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `document.write` use `.style`.

Example:

```
document.getElementById("your-element").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
```

[Click here](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html) to see the properties you can use.

For more features use jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

Comment: But when I try:
document.getElementById("fp").style.display = "none";
Strange enough nothing happened?

Comment: The display property is not supported by Javascript. See the link i provided.
In order to use all properties, use jQuery and .css() (see the second link).

Comment: Ok thank you, how can I use jQuery in JS or is that not possible?

Comment: Oh, that's very easy. Download the include file from [jquery.com](http://jQuery.com/download), include it and you're done :)

jQuery is JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to test by IP address do it on the server befor you send the page out

Answer (score -1):

Use either hash changes to window.location instead of the full URL re-write or "push" the URL change using History API

Comment: Hashbangs are ruining the Internet since everything after hash isn't considered part of the URL, this is terrible advice.

Comment: @Esko, I hope you don't mind using History API, do you? Then, the advise is not as terrible as it seems, I would say. But, yeah, I hear you.